# Jenkins: NullPointerException at ':app:processDevManifest' task step

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I'm working on the Android Gradle project for the first time. I was successfully able to run the Android project from command line on my Mac locally using `./gradlew assembleDev`

Now, the problem I'm having is to run the Jenkins job for the project. I have the following in my Jenkins Job:

**Environment variables:**

1. Under Jenkins configuration > Global properties > Environment variables > a. ANDROID_HOME, GRADLE_USER_HOME and JAVE_HOME

**Execute Shell Step:**

1. Only one step (`./gradlew assembleDev`) in my Jenkin's job.
2. Please note: I also tried `gradle assembleDev` instead `./gradlew assembleDev` and also tried `Invoke Gradle Script` step instead of the `Execute Shell`. (All these trials gave me the same error below)

When I run this job I get this error:

```
13:11:08 + ./gradlew assembleDev --stacktrace
13:11:09 Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
13:11:14 
13:11:14 > Configure project :app
13:11:14 WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
13:11:14 It will be removed at the end of 2019.
13:11:14 For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
13:11:14 To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
13:11:17 
13:11:17 > Task :app:objectboxPrepareBuild
13:11:17 > Task :app:preBuild
13:11:17 > Task :app:preDevBuild
13:11:17 > Task :app:compileDevAidl NO-SOURCE
13:11:17 > Task :app:checkDevManifest UP-TO-DATE
13:11:17 > Task :app:compileDevRenderscript NO-SOURCE
13:11:17 > Task :app:generateDevBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
13:11:17 > Task :app:javaPreCompileDev UP-TO-DATE
13:11:17 > Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDev UP-TO-DATE
13:11:17 > Task :app:mergeDevShaders UP-TO-DATE
13:11:17 > Task :app:compileDevShaders UP-TO-DATE
13:11:17 > Task :app:generateDevAssets UP-TO-DATE
13:11:17 > Task :app:mergeDevAssets UP-TO-DATE
13:11:17 > Task :app:processDevGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
13:11:18 > Task :app:createDevCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
13:11:18 > Task :app:generateDevResValues UP-TO-DATE
13:11:18 > Task :app:generateDevResources UP-TO-DATE
13:11:18 > Task :app:processDevManifest FAILED
13:11:18 
13:11:18 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
13:11:18 
13:11:18 * What went wrong:
13:11:18 Execution failed for task ':app:processDevManifest'.
13:11:18 > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
13:11:18 
13:11:18 * Try:
13:11:18 Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
13:11:18 
13:11:18 * Exception is:
13:11:18 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDevManifest'.
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
13:11:18 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
13:11:18    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:877)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.base.Joiner.toString(Joiner.java:452)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.base.Joiner.appendTo(Joiner.java:109)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.base.Joiner.appendTo(Joiner.java:152)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.base.Joiner.join(Joiner.java:195)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.base.Joiner.join(Joiner.java:185)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.base.Joiner.join(Joiner.java:211)
13:11:18    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask.lambda$serializeMap$0(ManifestProcessorTask.java:192)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$6.transform(Iterators.java:785)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.addAll(Iterators.java:358)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:147)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.castOrCopyToCollection(Iterables.java:306)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.toArray(Iterables.java:295)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.sortedCopy(Ordering.java:851)
13:11:18    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask.serializeMap(ManifestProcessorTask.java:190)
13:11:18    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest.getManifestPlaceholders(ProcessApplicationManifest.java:402)
13:11:18    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest_Decorated.getManifestPlaceholders(Unknown Source)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue$1$1.create(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:75)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:341)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue$1.get(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:72)
13:11:18    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:167)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue.call(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:119)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.AbstractValidatingProperty.validate(AbstractValidatingProperty.java:37)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultTaskProperties.validate(DefaultTaskProperties.java:184)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:54)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
13:11:18    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
13:11:18    ... 24 more
13:11:18 
13:11:18 
13:11:18 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
13:11:18 
13:11:18 BUILD FAILED in 9s
13:11:18 12 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 10 up-to-date
13:11:19 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
13:11:19 Performing Post build task...
```

I looked into similar failures (not exact) in other Stackoverflow answers but nothing worked for me. I'm not sure why it only fails on Jenkins but not in my local (using Android studio or terminal)

Comment: Can You post this ```assembleDev``` task from Your  build.gradle? Have You tried to use ```./gradlew assembleDebug``` task instead? Maybe You will find tip in: https://medium.com/@mydogtom/tip-how-to-reuse-gradle-daemon-between-android-studio-and-terminal-df5232d63f38

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "You post this `assembleDev` task from Your build.gradle"? Also, `./gradlew assembleDebug` complained missing `google-services.json`. I'm still trying to figure out what is different in case of Jenkins? I mean I'm able to build using terminal but the same command doesn't work when I do it from my Jenkins job. Any idea?

Comment: It was my bad. The problem was due to environment variables. My local environment has some variables in my `bash_profile` but it wasn't in Jenkins. I just added those environment variables in my Jenkins environment variables and it worked smoothly